# How return variable in main thread like as callback?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode7

I have the following method in Objective c:

```
- (BOOL) authorize {

    OauthObject* oauthObj = [OauthObject sharedManager];

    [[Manager sharedManagerServerRequest] authorize:(oauthObj) and:login.text withPassword:password.text completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@", error);

        if(error == NULL && data != nil) { 
            self.requestSuccessfull = YES;

        } else {
            //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            // Display error
        }
    }];

    return self.requestSuccessfull;
 }
```

Inside this function there is method `authorize` that does request to server and returns data in block.

Problem is that `- (BOOL) authorize` returns faster `return self.requestSuccessfull` and it is FALSE always.

Comment: You're missing some basics about asynchronous development with blocks. you can't have dispatch queue return, it has it's own scope. @Abamazi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This request is asynchronous so you should use block for call back. You can change code to:

```
 - (void)authorize:(void (^)(BOOL result))completionHanlder {
    OauthObject* oauthObj = [OauthObject sharedManager];

    [[Manager sharedManagerServerRequest] authorize:(oauthObj) and:login.text withPassword:password.text completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@", error);

        if(error == NULL && data != nil) {
            completionHanlder(YES);

        } else {
            completionHanlder(NO);
            //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            // Display error
        }
    }];
}
```

And you can use like this:

```
[yourInstance authorize:^(BOOL result) {
    //user result here.
}];
```

Hope this help!